# Google Closure Compiler: Declaring properties in externs

Tags: properties, external, google-closure-compiler

I've just been trying to work out how to do this, and didn't find much on google, so I'll document what I found here.

I needed to define a JS class in an external library and also define some properties and method on it.  I could do methods and the class, but was hitting a wall with properties.

So how is it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's imagine I've got an external JS class called 'Bob'.

My closure externs for this would be:

```
/** @constructor */ var Bob = function() {};
```

If I had a method (flyAway(speed)) I would add:

```
Bob.prototype.flyAway = function(speed) {};
```

And if I had a property (currentSpeed) I would add:

```
Bob.prototype.currentSpeed;
```

(the last one, I was doing (stupidly in hindsight) Bob.currentSpeed;)